# Using Spring JdbcTemplate to extract two fields in a row

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

I am new to spring and my requiremnt is below:
Using spring jdbctemplate extract two fields in a row.

I tried using queryFOrObject() api, which is working for one field, but I do not sure how to use it for two fields ?

```
public String getSalarayAndSalaryCode(int id) {
   JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

   //not working
    String sql = "SELECT salary,sal_code FROM table WHERE ID=?";

   //working
    String sql = "SELECT sal_code FROM table WHERE ID=?";

     String output= (String) jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
        sql, new Object[] { id }, String.class);

   return output;
}
```

String sql = "SELECT salary,sal_code FROM table WHERE ID=?";

I want to get salary and sal_code in a single query.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this by using `queryForMap`

```
String sql = "SELECT salary,sal_code FROM table WHERE ID=?";
Map<String, Object> result =  (Map<String, Object>) jdbcTemplate
                              .queryForMap(sql, new Object[] {id});
```

So Map contains

```
     Key           column
   column name     value
   column name     value
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I needed. I do not want to create RowWrapper for this.. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;

public class SalaryRowMapper implements RowMapper
{
    public Object mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        Salary salary= new Salary();
        salary.setSalary(rs.getInt("salary"));
        salary.setSalaryCode(rs.getString("sal_code"));
        return salary;
    }
}
```

And change your code as below:

```
public String getSalarayAndSalaryCode(int id) {
   JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

    String sql = "SELECT salary,sal_code FROM table WHERE ID=?";

     String output= (String) jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
        sql, new Object[] { id }, new SalaryRowMapper());

   return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Create a POJO that has fields reflecting the desired select results.

**2)** Create a `RowMapper<Pojo>` and pass it as one of the parameters of the `queryForObject`. It can treated as a functional interface so you can pull off something like:

```
RowMapper<Pojo> pojoRowMapper = (ResultSet rs, int rowNumber) -> {
        Pojo res = new Pojo();

        res.setSalaryCode(rs.getString("sal_code"));
        ...
};
```